# Is $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ with $\{x: f(x)\neq 0\}$ finite automatically bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x∈[a,b]$ except for a finite number of points in $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is dis-continuous at these points but is $f$ still bounded on the compact interval?

Comment: Of course.... there's only a finite se of points $x$ where $|f(x)|\neq0$, so just take the maximum of these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A\subseteq[a,b]$ the set where $f\neq 0$. We know that the cardinality of $A$ is finite. Then, take $s=\max\{|f(x)|:x\in A\}$ (the maximum there exist because the set is finite) and clearly $|f|\leq s$. Thus, $f$ is bounded